# how do I resolve httpd conflict on amazon ec2 linux?

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install apache on my amazon ec2 instance.

when I use :

```
sudo yum -y install httpd
```

I get a conflict with httpd2.2

```
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
```

But I cannot remove the older version using:

```
yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
yum remove httpd
```

I just get the error

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
No Packages marked for removal
```

or 
    Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
    No Match for argument: hhtpd
    No Packages marked for removal

Im new to setting up these instances so any help would be appreciated in advance, thanks.

Comment: could you provide the AMI id that is used ..

Comment: ami-149f7863    PV
EBS-Backed
64-bit

Comment: It looks like a private AMI, I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I canot access the AMI Id you have mentioned. instead I used AMI `ami-d03ea1e0`. Here are hte steps I followed:

1. Created an instance
2. Installed `httpd.x86_64`
3. then treid to install `httpd24.x86_64` and recieved the error as yours
4. so removed `httpd.x86_64` and `httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64` and it was sucessful
5. was successfully able to install `httpd24.x86_64`

Here is the status:

```
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Amazon)
Server built:   Sep 20 2013 18:01:06

# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: AmazonAMI
Description:    Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09
Release:        2013.09
Codename:       n/a
```

It worked for me. Of course, the AMI I tried was a public one.

BTW, `lsb_release -a` doesn't work out of the box on aforementioned AMI. I had to install lsb package for that.